# Uniform Form Styling - Checkbox Radio

Tags: html, css, uniform

I am using the Uniform Plugin to Style Checkbox and Radio Buttons.

I am able to get the styling working but on click the selection is not happening. Since this doesnt require me to activate the styling manually JS it should work.

[Demo](http://noise.mink7.com/html/elements.html)

Comment: the css class `checked` is not added to the span around the `<input>`. sot sure why

Comment: the problem is occurring through your  `element.css` page

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem:

- You pre-formatted your HTMl like uniformwould do it by itself.
- And then you did not call `uniform()` to add its event-listeners.

---

So you just need pure HTMl-input tags.
instead of

```
<div class="checker"><span class="checked"><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="styled"></span></div>
```

You should write:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

---

JavaScript:

Finally you need to put something like this in your JS section, to get uniform working, and change the radio-class:

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    $("select, input, a.button, button").uniform({radioClass: 'choice'});
});
```

---

Your HTML is not pre-formatted, your radio-buttons still work with uniform and finally uniform works as intended

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz6Q/3/)**

Comment: ah.. okay :D is it advisable to activate it via the js only? i wondering like in bootstrap if we can activate js components via css itself